# Единственно потому что

Tags: союзы

Единственно тяну до августа, потому что посещаю репетиторий.

Может ли отделяться "единственно" от "потому что"? Каким тогда членом предложения является "единственно"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть всего 3 варианта связать слова "единственно" и "потому".

1. Поставить запятую перед `что` - связь на расстоянии:

   `Единственно тяну до августа потому, что посещаю репетиторий.`

   В этом случае связь осуществляется за счёт акцента голосом на слове `потому`. Если подчеркнуть `тяну`, то связи уже не будет.
2. Разделить составной союз:

   `Единственно потому тяну до августа, что посещаю репетиторий.`
3. Переставить слово `единственно` в конец:

   `Тяну до августа единственно потому, что посещаю репетиторий.`

Примечание: после `единственно` запятая не ставится.

Чем ближе слова, тем сильнее связь между ними. Следовательно, в вариантах №2,3 связь максимальная. Выбирайте то, что вам больше нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Запомните эти слова – «провокаторы», которые никогда не выделяются запятыми:

аналогично, буквально, **единственно**, в итоге, в результате, в связи с этим, именно, исключительно, как будто, к тому же, в конечном счете, большей частью, на редкость, непременно, особенно, определенно, по решению, по постановлению, приблизительно, только, тем не менее, то есть, словно.

[image]

В данном примере это частица.

Может отделяться от `потому что` как наречие, но структура такого предложения далеко не оптимальна:

`Это в своём роде единственно, потому что...`

Но таких примеров много не найти.

Comment: В моем случае "единственно" невозможно трактовать как наречие. Я бы хотел его так на расстоянии присоединить к "Потому что". Это ни в коем случае не возможно?

Comment: Возможно на расстоянии - с вводным оборотом: `единственно, наверное, потому что`. У вас `единственно` относится к `тяну`. Частицы всегда относятся к следующему слову.

Comment: `Единственно` здесь в значении `только`, Попробуйте заменить на это слово, чтобы легче было переделать под нужный вариант. И тут вы поймёте, что `только` не получается на расстоянии привязать к `потому что`. А с `единственно` та же история, просто это не так очевидно.

Comment: Почему? Вполне допускаю "Только тяну до августа потому, что..." Вы имеете в виду, что частицу в начале необходимо отделить? "Единственно, тяну до августа, потому что" - так что ли?

Comment: Вы очень непонятно сформировали сам вопрос. Никаких проблем нет, чтобы поставить запятую перед `что`. **Запятая может делить составной союз на две части, если по воле автора логический акцент делается на слово «потому»**. И никакие частицы на это не влияют. Но частица при этом не связывается с `потому`, а так и остаётся связана с `тяну`.  А то, что вы хотели, - перенести `потому` в предыдущее предложение. Это и нужно было спрашивать. А я понял вас буквально и пытался скрестить муху со слоном. Ну вот и разобрались. Но не сильно это слово подходит и звучит плохо. Лучше заменить на "просто".

Comment: Нет, вы все правильно поняли, речь шла о скрещивании усилит. частицы с союзом. Поэтому я и интересуюсь, может быть, чтобы связать их, необходимо поставить запятую после "единственно"?

Comment: По правилам нельзя после `единственно` поставить запятую, если дальше нет того, что её требует.  Да и запятая оборвала бы связь. Они и связываются, если поставить запятую перед `что`. Но хоть и грамматически такое предложение правильно,  а стилистически оно не грамотно и очень плохо такая связь звучит. Решение: разорвать составной союз `потому что`. Примеры из литературы показывают, что разрыв возможен. Ответ: `Единственно потому тяну до августа, что посещаю репетиторий.` Сейчас такие связи, какие вы хотите, не формируют. Но это очень характерно для фильмов про Царскую Россию.

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция, безусловно, не принадлежит к классическим литературным фразам, скорее разговорная. В разговорном стиле возможно отделение частицы от усиливаемого слова. Но если Вы присоединяете частицу единственно к "потому", то почему запятая **перед** "потому"? Логичнее было бы *Единственно тяну до августа потому, что посещаю репетиторий.* (Тяну до августа единственно (только, исключительно) потому, что посещаю репетиторий).

В предложенном виде возможно отнесение частицы к "до августа": *Тяну единственно (только) до августа, потому что посещаю репетиторий*. Но смысл тогда несколько другой.