# Вводное слово или частица (единственно, единственно что)?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, вводные-слова, частицы

***Единственно(,) обгорела,** хотя была в платье с рукавом и в перчатках.*

1. Это вопрос с сайта Мail.ru. https://otvet.mail.ru/question/230472237

Участникам предложение не понравилось: Единственно, обгорела? Не поняла смысл. Вообще все предложение построено просторечно. Что за слова "единственно" и платье "с рукавом"?

2. Так можно ли так писать? На форуме обсуждались похожие  вопросы, например;

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464114/Единственное-в-качестве-вводного-слова](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464114/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454357/Единственно-потому-что](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454357/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)

Но здесь – немного другая тема.

**И у меня такие вопросы:**

(1) Как вы оцените все предложение? Надо ставить запятую или нет?  А платье с рукавом – так можно говорить?

(2) Может лучше написать так: ***Единственно(,) что** обгорела, хотя была в платье с рукавом и в перчатках* (по аналогии с «разве что»). А здесь нужна запятая?

(3) Ваш вариант предложения?

Спасибо.